# BootDevice Not Found after swapping non-system HDD

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I have some odd behavior on an HP Elitebook 8570W that I cant quite explain.
The laptop comes w/ a primary SSD and has an upgrade bay.  This one had a 500GB 5400rpm drive.
When I swap the upgrade bay (the D:\ in Windows 10) for a new Samsung 500GB SSD the system will not boot....
BootDevice Not Found
Hard Disk - (3F0)

Pulled the D:\ out of the upgrade bay and left the upgrade bay empty...same error...it will not launch the OS, theres definitely some hardware juju here.
It will only start w/ the original D:\ in place.

So I connected the new HDD to a SATA to USB adapter, initialized the drive and copied the contents of D:\ over to the new drive...same error when I popped it into the upgrade bay.

The UEFI panel has an 'Upgrade Bay Hard Drive boot', which I've disabled to no effect.

One thing I find odd is that the UEFI Boot Order makes no mention of the primary Hard Drive...
it says only:

1. Notebook Upgrade Bay (UEFI)
2. OS Boot Manager
3. Notebook Ethernet

Swapping those does not seem to make a difference.
Finally, I switched UEFI to the Legacy Boot Order which DOES mention Notebook Hard Drive....I moved this first, above the Notebook Upgrade Bay...no help.

Out of ideas, and simply cant do anything without the orginal second HDD.

BTW, the UEFI does recognize the new SSD, and a quick test on it returns fine both before and after I initialized it in Windows...so I dont think its a dud.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your original drive probably has a extra hidden boot partition ...

Comment: That sounds intriguing.  I'll mount the old one so I can get back into Windows and see if I can whack it.  I did have hidden files visible when I copied all of the original contents onto the new SSD...only folder I did not overwrite was the lone System Volume Information.  I'm guessing the partition is not visible.  Any dangers to deleting the extra recovery partition on the non boot drive?